# Use tc to throttle Docker container's outgoing network bandwidth

Tags: docker, bandwidth-throttling, trafficshaping

I'm trying to do the bandwidth throttling to the Docker containers.
To limit the downlink bandwidth, I can first find the veth interface of the container and use tc: `tc qdisc add dev vethpair1 root tbf rate 1mbit latency 50ms burst 10000`. If I want to limit the uplink bandwidth, I need to specify `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` when I spin up the container and use the same tc command on `eth0` inside the container. Is there any non-intrusive way to do it, so that I can administrate any container without giving it privilege?

Answer (score 3):

You could tell Docker to use LXC under the hoods : use the `-e lxc`option.

```
Create your containers with a custom LXC directive to put them into a **traffic class** :

`docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.net_cls.classid = 0x00100001" your/image /bin/stuff`
```

Check the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_cls.txt) about how to apply bandwidth limits to this class.

Note : the `--storage-driver=devicemapper`and `-e lxc`options are for the Docker **daemon**, not for the Docker client you're using when running `docker run .......`.

ALso you can do this through this:

```
mkdir /var/run/netns
ln -sf /proc/`docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }}' YOUR_CONTAINER`/ns/net /var/run/netns/SOME_NAME
ip netns exec SOME_NAME iptables -L -nv
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried net_cls but it didn't work. Is it because I didn't use LXC abstraction? I'll try LXC later.